# Junit test failure returns [Microsoft][Pilote ODBC Microsoft Access]

Tags: ms-access, junit, odbc

I'm writing a set of test scenarios for my code, and currently I have a failure that isn't a failure.

Let me explain. I'm testing for the scenario that an incorrect file path is inserted into the class constructor.

This should throw either a connection error, or a file not found type error, but it in fact throws the error

```
[Microsoft][Pilote ODBC Microsoft Access] '(Inconnu)' n'est pas un chemin d'accès valide.
```

So this is kind of expected, but my unit test fails as I can't find the code for the

```
@test (expected=microsoft.odbc.error.class)
```

here is my current code block, all ideas are greately appreciated...

```
//test for a bad file name
    @Test (expected=java.sql.SQLException.class)
    public void failFileConnect()
    {
        this.reset();//reset and initialise our temp strings
        this.Report = new String();//initialise our report info string.

        //this file is imaginary, although it may look similar to the principle connect verstion it is not!
        MS_mdb tFile = new MS_mdb("c:\\path\\to\\non\\existant\\file\\will\\fail");

        File test = new File(tFile.getSchema());


        fail("cannot connect to imaginary file!");

    }//end test
```

In the class the connection is initialised with this code

```
schema = s; //the string file name passed into the method
String db = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="+schema+";";
```

thanks in advance...

David.

ps. I've considered using a very general error to capture, but would like this one, or some other JDBC / SQL tye error, but none of them work, the message doesn't seem to come from any of the.

D

Comment: so far no comments, if there is any info I can add to help, or to improve the question I will modify as required...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution...

It s maybe not teribly elegant but, it helps to give me (or a user in the same situation) a handle on why the code may fail.

I have simply set a logging output message that states what the possible causes may be.

something along the lines of...

Unable to connect to specified DB. This may be an incorrect file name (or path) or some other strange SQL problem (if using an embeded DB, is the file currently opened by another user). Confirm the path to the file and the presence (or not) of a lock file on the database.

At least it gives me an idea of what is going on... I guess I could otherwise set a strange error number against it of my own devising ;)

David